# How to set no tabs in TextMate

Tags: text-editor, textmate

I do not want tabs as symbols in Textmate. 
I would like to them be for instance 4 spaces.

How can you make each 'tab' be 4 spaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this in your ~/.tm_properties:

```
tabSize         = 4
softTabs        = true
```